# deployment of persistence unit failed close all factories

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish, eclipselink, ejb-3.1

Much love for Ur good works, I'm having an issue with glassfish server 4 while deploying my ejb-jar. I have xampp installed so I'm using mysql from there. I'm also using netbeans. I created a data source for mysql using the connector/j driver, then I'm using this as my jta data source. I cant seem to find any solution on-line. Thanks This is the stack trace for the exception:

```
INFO:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b

WARNING:   Problem while unregistering MBean: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: TopLink:Name=Development-file_/C_/Users/FOO/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Project/Project-ejb/build/classes/_Project-ejbPU,Type=Configuration

WARNING:   Problem while unregistering MBean: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: TopLink:Name=Session(file_/C_/Users/FOO/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Project/Project-ejb/build/classes/_Project-ejbPU)

INFO:   file:/C:/Users/FOO/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Project/Project-ejb/build/classes/_Project-ejbPU logout successful

SEVERE:   java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.DatabaseField.hashCode(DatabaseField.java:400)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:874)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.getFieldClassification(OneToOneMapping.java:882)

SEVERE:   Exception while deploying the app [Project-ejb]

SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing

org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [Project-ejbPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createDeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:451)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:492)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:398)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I followed the full trace 'til reach sth related to my code, in my case I had a trouble with  one namedQuery:

*Grave:   Excepción al desplegar la aplicación [segeca_restful] : Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [segeca_restfulPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
**Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT p FROM Peticion p WHERE p.usuarioIdusuario.idusuario := idusuario]. 
[31, 73] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.***

Maybe in your case the root cause could be another one, but I think that if you examine the glassfish's logs, you'll find it.

Good luck,

Regards,

Karl.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have experienced similar issue but the root cause was different. I am using one and same persistence project for several Web projects. So the solution for me was to un-deploy all projects from application server. Rebuild them and deploy only project I need. There was some cache.